# Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with ID xxx

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

What is causing the error

> "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with ID ..."

in my Google Apps Script code?

How can I fix this error and successfully import an Excel sheet (at the moment that sheet is located on Google drive, can I load it from my hard drive, when I run the script) into existing Google Sheet using Google Apps Script?

Is there a specific configuration or permission that needs to be set in order for the code to access and read an Excel file from Google Drive?

I am not very familiar with Google Apps Script and any advices are welcomed.

Here is my script

```
function importExcelSheet() {
// Ask which Excel file to load
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the Excel file to load:")).next();

// Read the Excel file
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);

// Get the first sheet from the Excel file
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

// Import the sheet into the active Google Sheet
var currentSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var newSheet = currentSpreadsheet.insertSheet(sheet, 0);

// Set the name of the new sheet in the format "YYYY.MMM"
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var monthName = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT", "MMM");
newSheet.setName(year + "." + monthName);
}

// Add the function to the Custom Google Sheet menu
function onOpen() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var menuEntries = [{name: "Import Excel Sheet", functionName: "importExcelSheet"}];
spreadsheet.addMenu("Custom Menu", menuEntries);
}
```

```
I added "Drive API" to the Apps Script from "Services" menu.
```

Comment: do ou have access to that file?

Comment: yes i am the owner of the files

Comment: can i get an example of what you are adding here Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the Excel file to load:")

Comment: I am entering the name of the uploaded file, e.g. "FileName.xlsx" (without the quotes). The file is located in my Google Drive.

Comment: is it an xlsx mime type or is it a Google sheets mime type.   When uploaded was it converted to a Google sheet?

Comment: I Have tested xlsx file I get same problem, seems spreadsheet.open opens only google sheet files, the solution is convert excel to G sheet file, to see more here the link https://spreadsheet.dev/automatically-convert-excel-spreadsheets-to-google-sheets-using-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

This should work (haven't tested it) but this is not perfect because creating a copy of your source file, in order to read it with SpreadsheetApp

And you need to activate Advanced Drive API : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive

```
// your code:
// Ask which Excel file to load
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the Excel file to load:")).next();

//then: 
if (file.getContentType() == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || file.getContentType() == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") {

   var id = Drive.Files.insert({title: "new", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, file.copyBlob()).id;
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);

   //back to your code
}
```